# Why have to use friend function

Tags: c++, friend

I am trying to overload operator '=' and operator '<<' by the same method.

```
class Vect{
 public:
  //..
   Vect& operator=(const Vect& a);      
   ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Vect& vect);
  //..
 private:
  int *data;
  int size;
};
```

this work

```
Vect& Vect:: operator=(const Vect& a){
 //.. 
 //copy data operator
 for(int i = 0; i< size; i++){
  data[i] = a.data[i];
 }
 return *this;
}
```

however: this code cause error
[Error] 'std::ostream& Vect::operator<<(std::ostream&, const Vect&)' must take exactly one argument

```
ostream& Vect::operator<<(ostream& out, const Vect& vect){
 //.. print vect
}
```

I am reading "Data structure and algorithms in C++" book part (1.5.4).
They said i have to use class friends for overloading '<<' operator because it is **access private members data**.
 I don't understand why. Overloading '=' operator i also access private member data without using "friend".

Comment: Aren't you curious about the error you got? Because it doesn't say anything about accessing private data members. (although that will likely also be a problem, once you fix the problem that's causing the current error).

Answer (score 3):

When you put a function declaration inside the class definition, it becomes by default a member function, so...

```
class Vect {
  public:
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Vect& vect);
};
```

...won't compile as it requests creation of a `<<` function that takes too many arguments arguments: any member function `operator<<` is expected to use `*this` as the "left hand side" argument, and take one other argument to be the "right hand side".

You have two options:

- Replace the above with `friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Vect& vect);`, which tells the compiler that the function is a friend of the surrounding class, but not a member thereof.  As a non-member, the two arguments it operates on are `out` and `vect` - there is no `*this` object involved.  That all works fine, and being a `friend` the definition also has access to private and protected member data in `vect`.
- Move the `operator<<` declaration outside the `class Vect` definition; that also makes it a non-member function, but that *doesn't* make it a friend.

Answer (score 2):

> Overloading '=' operator i also access private member data without using "friend"

`operator=` is declared as a member function, which can access the private member.

> They said i have to use class friends for overloading '<<' operator because it is access private members data. I don't understand why.

The problem is you're declaring `operator<<` as a member function, which should be declared as a non-member function. That's why you got the error.

`operator<<` should be a non-member function, because it needs a different type as its left-hand argument, i.e. `std::ostream&`, instead of `Vect&` when declared as a member function.

That means, as a non-member function, `operator<<` couldn't access the private member of the class unless you declare it as friend, such as:

```
class Vect {
public:
  //..
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Vect& vect);
  //..
```

Note the above syntax makes `operator<<` a non-member function now.